# Typescript with Prisma

Tags: typescript, prisma

I'm completely new to Typescript.

I've started to work with Prisma and, coming from Sequelize, I miss simply writing stuff e.g. `user.update({ ... })`. It seems that Prisma returns just plain objects, and not classes, so I came up with this:

```js
import { Prisma, User as PrismaUser } from '@prisma/client';
import prisma from './path-to-prisma-instance';

class User {
  constructor(data: PrismaUser) {
    Object.assign(this, data);
  }

  update = async (props: Prisma.UserUpdateArgs) => {
    const data = await prisma.user.update({
      ...props,
      where: { id: this.id } // Property 'id' does not exist on type 'User'
    });
    return new User(data);
  };
}
```

I'm getting that `Property 'id' does not exist on type 'User'`.

How am I able to fix this?

Comment: Maybe you should first try using Prisma the way it is intended too?

Comment: @GuillaumeBrunerie That's super helpful. I just thought Prisma is a tool, and its team also learns by looking at how people use their product. Maybe this is why they started developing extensions ;)